# CASE Statement to check if any field is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, case

There are two fields in my table cust_shipmentdate_awb and comp_shipdate_awb. Iam trying to write a CASE Statement which should check both fields cust_shipmentdate_awb and comp_shipdate_awb is null or empty. If both are  Null then show the result as 'Pending'. If any one field is not empty, then it should show as 'Completed' AND if both fields are entered also it should as 'Completed'. I have tried the below CASE statement. But its showing pending when both the fields data is entered. Iam trying to achieve as per the below data.

```
============================================================
cust_shipmentdate_awb | comp_shipdate_awb | shipment_status
============================================================

   02-03-2016         |                   | Completed
                      | 09-08-2016        | Completed
   NULL               | NULL              | Pending
   01-06-2016         | 09-08-2016        | Completed
============================================================

CASE    
    When cust_shipmentdate_awb Is Null Or comp_shipdate_awb = '' Then 'Pending'   
    Else 'Completed' End AS shipment_status
```

Comment: Can you add the statement with the filled in data instead of the columns if it is executed?

Comment: Why do you want to do that with SQL? Why not simply with PHP?

Comment: Iam trying to edit which been coded by someone else. Just revamping some errors. so i dont want to change lot of things.

Comment: @rbr94. Pls check now

Comment: Anyone to help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use the `AND` operator and check both fields for null and empty (''):

```
CASE    
    When        (cust_shipmentdate_awb Is Null OR cust_shipmentdate_awb = '') 
            AND (comp_shipdate_awb Is Null OR comp_shipdate_awb = '') Then 'Pending' 
    Else 'Completed' End AS shipment_status
```